# Having one backend manage authentication for a webapp and react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, jwt, passport.js

Im planning on making an application that has two parts two it:

1. React native mobile app
2. Browser web-app for desktop users

I'm trying to plan out how im going to manage the backend authentication for this (Node.js, passport.js). Ideally, I can just have one backend manage it, regardless of which type of client.

Lets say im going to ONLY have google auth (for simplicity). I don't need to hit googles API's for any information (like profile, contacts, etc), I just want them to login with a google account. My understanding so far is that theres two main ways (especially since im using passport.js).

1. jwt based approach
2. session based approach

For either approach, my issue arises when it comes to the react native app. Since I'm not able to use the `HttpOnly` cookie, im not sure how to safely store data. e.g

1. In the jwt approach, if the server administers an access token and a refresh token, the react native client can just store them both in the same place e.g https://github.com/mcodex/react-native-sensitive-info. Which means the refresh token is just as susceptible as the access token, which defeats the point of a refresh token, so might as well just have the access token be long lived.
2. In the session based approach, react native can just store the session id some where (like react-native-sensitive-info above), and the same problem arises

My current thoughts on what should be done:

It seems like theres no way of getting around the security issue of storing information in react native, so as of now I feel like im just going to follow the JWT approach, and store the access + refresh token in react-native-sensitive-info. However, this does mean that the login endpoint is going to return the access + refresh token in the body of the request when the User-agent is mobile. When the user agent is web then we should be able to set an httponly cookie. The only thing that I can think of is if there is a malicious request that masks the user agent (is this possible?), and then can receive the access + refresh token in the body and will be able to do whatever with that.

***Performance Aside***

A session based storage approach seems much simpler overall. Yes it does store state on the backend, but if we did the JWT approach we would have to store peoples refresh tokens somewhere on the backend anyway (If theres ever a scenario where we need to invalidate peoples refresh tokens, e.g on logout or damage prevention).

This way, say we have a sessions table, when a user logs out, or if we want to invalidate sessions, all we have to do is delete rows from that table. In the JWT method, if we want to invalidate a refresh token, we have to have a blocklist table (which will only keep growing in size, since refresh tokens shouldn't expire, but I guess they can be dropped after a long period of time). However, if you have LOTS of users, the sessions table could get large, which could cause performance issues (but you could probably just drop sessions over a certain age)

***/Aside***

Questions:

- Ive noticed mobile applications have NEVER asked me to relogin with OAuth. Does that mean they're constantly using their refresh token whenever the access token expires? If theres no clear way to store that in a secure way in mobile, do they just have super long lasting access tokens?
- Is all of this thinking overkill? Is it fine to just store a super long-lasting access-token in react native and just use that all the time? Then when the user presses 'logout' we can drop that from local storage?
- Would a third party auth system like auth0 manage all of this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to share my experiencies in different kinds of app, this way things may get more clear.

### Authentication Method

- On most of the mobile applications (with web applications) I've worked with long term access tokens on the mobile side, most of applications don't require the user to login each time you open the app. Usually we store the token in a Secure Storage.
- In some cases I've worked with a memory database (Redis) to put the user's session it's really fast and you don't need to query your main database each request (this was used for a high availability system, it may be overkill for most usecases)
- Some very specific solutions may require more security, this will depend on your product (like banks, and transactions apps or apps the keep sensitive data) in these cases I would recommend you to login the user every time he closes the app or stays inactive for to long. (this kind of solution usually relies on fingerprint/faceId libs)

My personal opinion on this matter is to go with jwt, it's easy to maintain on the server side if you need to change backends and has a more defined pattern to follow, but that's my opinion and if you have high demand or some specific usecase this may change.

### Storage

Talking about the storage options, there are some good suggestions on where to save data like tokens in a secure way on the react native docs,a good option I've used sometime would be:

https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage

but you can see more options and it advantages here:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#secure-storage

### Third party libs

They usually helps with the basics if your projects has the budget and not a lot of customization on the authentication process, usually if it's a brand new project (on the back and front end) they work well.
Most of them will handle most of the hurdle for you like token renovation but you should mind the price scalability for these kind of approach

Wish success on your project.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth reply! Yeah im definitely learning towards a JWT approach with longer lasting tokens for mobile (one hour access token, multiple months refresh token), along side a way to invalidate the refresh token (Would need to store a table of invalid refresh tokens, and add them in on user signout)

Comment: Yeah invalidating usually goes like that, you can clear your table when the token time expires as well, so you don't waste resources.
If you have a lot of users or your base grow to fast you can use a replica database with Redis to keep performance, just make sure to consolidate the database somewhere as Redis is a memory database.